# Finding the local maximum of a rational function in R

Tags: r, optimization

How would I find the local maximum of a rational (polynomial) function such as f(x) = 500*t/(2*t^2 + 9) in R?  I tried the following:

```
t <- seq(0,10000,by=0.000001)
f <- 500*t/(2*t^2 + 9)
max(f)
```

But I quickly ran out of memory.

Comment: See `?optimize`

Comment: If you check `curve(500*x/(2*x^2 + 9), from = 0, to = 10000)`, you'll see most of that range is definitely not the maximum, so your current approach is generating a really unnecessarily large vector. By adjusting `from` and `to` a bit, you can narrow the domain to [1, 3] pretty quickly. Or let `optimise` do it all for you, which is quite a lot more efficient.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks, guys.  I figured it out with the optimize command.

Comment: You can also consider function optim.

Comment: I'll check it out, papgeo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is how I did it.  Thanks to G. and alistaire.

```
f <- function(x){
  z <- 500*x/(2*x^2+9)
  return(z)
}

optimize(f,c(0,1000),maximum=TRUE)

Output:
$`maximum`
[1] 2.121332

$objective
[1] 58.92557
```

Comment: Just a comment. Note that you can easily get the numerator of the derivative. It is `9-2*t^2` up to a factor and its positive root is `t = 3/sqrt(2) = 2.12...`. So the result is correct :)